# Configuration webconfig issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

```xml
<roleManager enabled="true" />
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add    
      name="MyMembershipProvider"     
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"   
      connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"  
      minRequiredPasswordLength="2"     
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

It gives me an error:

Line 247:           
Line 248:               
Line 249:               
Line 250:

> add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" //this is shown in red. the line is in the machine.config file

Comment: Do you have a question? Is this stopping your application from running? Do you have .NET 4.0 installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format seems goofed up. Membership and RoleManager are two completely separate elements, not intertwined:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="MyMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Database" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
           connectionStringName="Database" 
           applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```